# R function for reading API from the National Assessment of Educational Progress (NAEP)

Tags: r, api

I am trying to download data from the NAEP API (https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/api_documentation.aspx)
but have only worked with .json API's in the past, taking advantage of the Rsocrata package.

I am new to API's and got lucky accessing some CDC data, already in .json format. Any guidance on accessing the above through R would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Hello Mark. Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

The NAEP API produces results in JSON. Absent a minimal, reproducible example we will convert one of the [sample API queries](https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/api_documentation.aspx#bookmark-02-Request) from the NAEP website, a basic data request, and store it in a data frame. We'll use the `jsonlite` package to process the API query.

```
aQuery <- "https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/Dataservice/GetAdhocData.aspx?type=data&subject=writing&grade=8&subscale=WRIRP&variable=GENDER&jurisdiction=NP&stattype=MN:MN&Year=2011"

library(jsonlite)
aResult <- data.frame(fromJSON(aQuery))
aResult
```

...and the output:

```
> aResult
  status result.year result.sample result.yearSampleLabel result.Cohort
1    200        2011            R3                   2011             2
2    200        2011            R3                   2011             2
  result.CohortLabel result.stattype result.subject result.grade result.scale
1            Grade 8           MN:MN            WRI            8        WRIRP
2            Grade 8           MN:MN            WRI            8        WRIRP
  result.jurisdiction result.variable result.variableLabel result.varValue
1                  NP          GENDER               Gender               1
2                  NP          GENDER               Gender               2
  result.varValueLabel result.value result.isStatDisplayable result.errorFlag
1                 Male     139.0995                        1                0
2               Female     158.5671                        1                0
>
```

We can eliminate the unnecessary `result.` prefixes on the column names with the following code.

```
# eliminate "result." from column names
colnames(aResult) <- sub("result.","",colnames(aResult))
aResult
```

...and the results:

```
> aResult
  status year sample yearSampleLabel Cohort CohortLabel stattype subject grade
1    200 2011     R3            2011      2     Grade 8    MN:MN     WRI     8
2    200 2011     R3            2011      2     Grade 8    MN:MN     WRI     8
  scale jurisdiction variable variableLabel varValue varValueLabel    value
1 WRIRP           NP   GENDER        Gender        1          Male 139.0995
2 WRIRP           NP   GENDER        Gender        2        Female 158.5671
  isStatDisplayable errorFlag
1                 1         0
2                 1         0
```